# Getting the last timestep of the last sequence exceeding the mean using R

Tags: r, sequence

I am trying to get the last time-step of the last sequence (at least 2 time steps) exceeding the mean using R.
I'll explain the details below.

```
tstep,val
1,5.0314285714
2,1.76
3,0.2742857143
4,0.2564285714
5,1.3666666667
6,0.2978571429
7,1.0028571429
8,1.2171428571
9,0.0371428571
10,0
11,0.0464285714
12,0.5928571429
13,1.2142857143
14,0
15,0.0285714286
16,0.3628571429
17,0.1085714286
18,0.2542857143
19,0
20,0
21,0.8914285714
22,1.1771428571
23,4.7514285714
24,2.9457142857
25,2.3628571429
26,0.96
27,16.115
28,10.5914285714
29,2.9878571429
30,2.3057142857
31,10.885
32,20.7285714286
33,59.2571428571
34,17.4714285714
35,16.3764285714
36,3.3457142857
37,18.2085714286
38,10.8742857143
39,10.38
40,37.9742857143
41,16.2628571429
42,2.1228571429
43,11.32
44,26.9285714286
45,9.98
46,25.9580952381
47,35.2438095238
48,24.5321428571
49,8.6857142857
50,5.1007142857
51,0.5085714286
52,3.9057142857
53,37.6857142857
54,3.5285714286
55,22.2342857143
56,11.3828571429
57,6.62
58,1.5542857143
59,1.8828571429
60,5.9778571429
61,6.9364285714
62,4.1885714286
63,3.9742857143
64,0.1742857143
65,1.6914285714
66,19.0057142857
67,0.8628571429
68,0.8057142857
69,0.3628571429
70,0.4714285714
71,0.7928571429
72,3.7657142857
73,0.6657142857
```

Suppose, for example, I have the above data (2 columns; 1 column for time step and 1 column for the value). I can get the timesteps with values above the mean as:

```
dat <- read.csv("test.csv",header=T,sep=",")
exceed <- which(dat$val>mean(dat$val))
```

and I get the following results:

```
[1] 27 28 31 32 33 34 35 37 38 39 40 41 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 53 55 56 66
```

What I want to get:

a). The last sequence exceeding the threshold (at least two time steps) is 55 56. I want to get 56 (the last time step of the sequence) in this example. I will be applying this for several files.

Any suggestion on how to do this easily in R?

I'll appreciate any help. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what are you trying to find. 56 is the second from the last? Do you need this element?

Comment: @m0nhawk--Thank you for the comment. I edited my post. The last sequence exceeding the threshold is 55 56. I want to get 56. I will apply this for many files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have `exceed`:

```
exceed <- c(27, 28, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 53, 55, 56, 66)

# this will split the exceed into list of consecutive numbers
consecutive <- split(exceed, cumsum(c(1, diff(exceed) != 1)))

# this will get item with index of last group of length 2 or more
last_consecutive <- consecutive[[max(which(sapply(consecutive, length) >= 2))]]

# get last number of last consecutive group    
res <- last_consecutive[length(last_consecutive)]
> res
[1] 56
```